# How do NAND flash memory writes work?

Tags: embedded, flash

Below is a picture of my understanding of NAND flash memory operation.

NAND flash works by first erasing all the cells in a single block (essentially setting it to '1') and then selectively writing 0's. My question is- Since the word line is shared between all cells in a single Page, how does the NAND controller programmer a 0 into specific cells in a page?

For the NOR flash, it is easy to see that a specific cells can be programmed by using Hot electron injection (Applying a high voltage across a cell). But with NAND, its not possible to do so since NAND cells are in series with each other, and its not possible to apply high voltage to specific cells. So what's done in NAND is quantum tunneling, where the Word line is given a high voltage to write a 0. What's not clear to me is how can this voltage be made selective (in other words since the word lines are shared between cells in a page, the high voltage for programming a single bit to 0 shouldn't also 0 out the other bits in a page).

[image: NAND memory array organization]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The image below is the more detailed version of your NAND FLash memory array organization in the question. The NAND flash memory array is partitioned into **blocks** that are, in turn sub-divided into **pages**. A **page** is the smallest granularity of data that can be addressed by the **external controller**.

[image: A NAND Flash Memory Array - Figure 2.2 from the Master's Thesis linked below]

[Above image is Figure 2.2 "A NAND Flash Memory Array" from: **Vidyabhushan Mohan**. *Modeling the Physical Characteristics of NAND Flash Memory*. Master's Thesis. University of Virginia, Charlottesville. May 2010.](https://itzbhushan.gitlab.io/files/Thesis.pdf)

To perform a **program operation**, in other words writing "**0**"s to the desired cells, the **external memory controller** needs to determine the physical address of the page to be programmed. For each write operation, a **free valid page** needs to be chosen because NAND flash does not allow in-place update operation. The controller then transmits the
**program command**, the data to be programmed and the physical address of the page to the chip.

When a request for a program operation arrives from the controller, a row of the memory array (**corresponding to the requested page**) is selected and the **latches** in the **page buffer** are loaded with the data to be written. The **SST** is then **turned on** while the **GST** is **turned off** by the control unit. For **FN tunneling** to occur, a high electric field is necessary across the floating gate and the substrate. This high electric field is achieved by setting the control gate of the selected row to a
high voltage **Vpgm**, and biasing the bit-lines corresponding to logical **“0”** to **ground**.

This creates a high potential difference across the floating gate and the substrate causing electrons to tunnel from the substrate onto the floating gate. For “**1**” programming (which is basically non-programming), the memory cell should remain in the same state as before the program operation. While different techniques are adopted to prevent tunneling of electrons for such cells, we assume the self-boosted
program inhibit operation.

This technique provides the necessary program inhibit voltage by driving the bit-lines corresponding to logical “**1**” to **Vcc** and by **turning on** the **SSL** and **turning off** the **GSL**. When the word-line of the selected row rises to **Vpgm** , the series capacitance through the control gate, floating gate, channel and the bulk are coupled, boosting the channel
potential automatically and preventing FN tunneling.

---

This information was taken and summarized from [here](https://itzbhushan.gitlab.io/files/Thesis.pdf) and more details of programming NAND Flash memory can be found from that source as well.

Comment: Thanks for summarizing the Thesis you pointed out to. Could you explain a bit more in simpler terms how the cells that are to be left at '1' are not affected by the tunneling happening on the shared word line? From what I understood in the excerpt you posted, the all those bits that have the same shared wordline are also assigned the same voltage to the corresponding bits. Due to this, the electric field across the floating gate for such transistors is low enough that their value is retained to '1'. Also, why is GSL turned off, how does GSL help?

Comment: Basically in simple terms, the presence or absence of charges inside the FGT causes a shift in the Vthreshold of the FGT which is used to distinguish a logical “1” from a logical “0”. A single FGT is never programmed alone. Only a group of FGTs
is programmed at a time; this group of FGTs correspond to a page in this case, and this explains why NAND is block addressed instead of bit addressed. Hope this is clear.

Comment: You say "by turning on the SSL" but there is nothing on the schematic called SSL. Also, your "here for more details" is a dead link.

Comment: @Steev - Thanks for highlighting that the original links were dead. I've found a working link to the thesis which was used as the basis of this answer, and updated the links above. See [here](http://itzbhushan.gitlab.io/) for the thesis writer's page, which includes that thesis.